# Convergence of $\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\log^n(n)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a series convergence problem:

$$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\log^n(n)}$$

How do I simplify $\log^n(n)$?

**(Don't post direct answers, only pointers)**

Comment: Isn't that simple enough?

Comment: I don't know any theorems that apply to $log^n(n)$. What else is $log^n(n)$ anyways, rather than $log(n)*log(n)*log(n)*...$? Could this be raised to the exponent of $e$?

Comment: I don't think it can be simplified... If you want to find the series converges or not, you can simply apply ratio test...

Comment: @Asydot Ratio test? What for? Simply note that $(\log n)^n>2^n$ for every $n\ge8$.

Comment: @Asydot Can this fulfill the ratio test requirement $a_n ≠ 0 \space\forall \space n\in\mathbb{N}$? The sequence of the terms is converging towards 0.

Comment: I can't see why it can be zero. Converging to zero doesn't mean for any $n$ it will actually be zero. And I also think it is as Did said.

Comment: CAUCHY CONDENSATION  TEST

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can use the Cauchy root test.

Comment: Oh yeah, this is actually pretty trivial.

Comment: Although. How is $\frac{1}{\log(n)}$ < 1 for some $n$, $n≥3$? It is for large enough $n$, but how to give a more precise lower bound?

Comment: $\log{n} \geq \log{3} > \log{e}=1$. Inverting will give  your claim. Btw it is not necessary to find a small lower bound for Cauchy's radical test. Imagine you find a very large $N$ where convergence can be found. Then simply break the sum into a first half (which has a finite value) and the rest (which will converge because of the radical test)

Comment: How does one know $3 > e$ without knowing $e$'s decimal representation?

Comment: $e=\lim_{n\to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$. Expand this series using the Binomial formula and find the upper bound, which turns out to be 3. But seriously, i think you can assume that $2,7<e<2,8$, without deriving something. It is just a well known fact.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\log^n(n)=\exp(n\log\log n)$, for any $n>e^e$, is greater than $e^n$.